# Where should I ask my profiling question?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have a question about profiling results I got with webgrind (php). I identified three possible site where I could ask my question: SO, programmers and Software Quality Assurance (and Code Review, thanks ChrisF). In which case should I use one site over another for my profiling question?

Comment: Don't forget Code Review!

Comment: @ChrisF Yeah, it can be something, I added it to the list.

Comment: And what is your question about?

Comment: @Padded: Well I didn't want to give up too much details, as I may have more than one question in the future, but the problem I have now is the following: I've got this big function which is recognized as taking 70% of the execution time of the script, but inside it I only have some reference to php functions which takes each less than one percent, and they don't add up to the total. My questions could be in no particular order of preference: how should I interpret that? What tools would complement webgrind? What should I do now? How do I format my code for better compliance with webgrind? etc.

Comment: That's more then one question. The first part is On-Topic on Stack Overflow, the rest...not so.

Comment: @Padded: Well I see it more as a question seen from different angle. And to be honest my initial question was "what should I do now?" The other question came up while redacting the comment.

Comment: You can always ask that question on Stack Overflow, showing us the results of the profiling and your source code and asking why it turned up like this. Worst case is that your question will be downvoted because it is something obvious which you just missed. State it as generic as possible and maybe do even some testing before you post it, so that you can provide a way to reproduce the issue. Especially the last thing is crucial, it might already yield the answer you're looking for.

Comment: @Padded: What testing? I mean there is no bug, the process is just very slow.

Comment: I thought you said that one function is consuming 70%, but the call in it only 1%? That sounds like a problem with the profiler. On the other hand, if you were just looking for code optimization help, go to Code Review.

Comment: @PaddedCell: your comment helped me sort my problem out, as I made a misinterpretation. Nevertheless, I am still interested in the answer to my post here. Maybe we could clean up our comments, maybe making an exception with your bigger comment which give some good advice, what do you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As usual, the answer is: *It depends* <sup>tm</sup>.

**Suitable for Stack Overflow**

- Confusing or seemingly wrong profiler results. *(Note: We will not analyze the results themselves, we will not do the work for you)*
- Confusing or seemingly wrong behavior of the profiler.
- Problems with setting up and testing in combination with the profiler. *(Note: Read the README first, we will still not do the work for you)*

**Suitable for Programmers**

- How to incorporate a profiler into your work flow
- What are the benefits of using a profiler and why/when should I use one

**Suitable for Code Review**

- I've profiled this code (code and profiling results provided) and how can it be made faster

**Suitable for the Stack Exchange Super Hot Extreme High Temperature Emergency Intelligence Incinerator**

- Why is not work?
- Why is codes not work fast?
- How do I use a profiler?
- What does this profiler result mean?

**What should I do first if I have a question fitting on Stack Overflow?**

Always, for the sake of the Flying Spaghetti Monster, *always* try to create a simple scenario in which you can reproduce anomalies and problems. This will also help you see things which might have simply missed.